# conditional CSS in HTML class tag LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

very simple but stuck. I used conditional CSS  in a js file

```
get  styleClass(){
 return this.show ? 'class0': 'class1';
    }
```

In the HTML file, the div class looks like

`<div   class="slds-box slds-p-left_xxx-small slds-theme_default card">`
Now  how can i put `{styleClass}`  in div class like
`<div   class="slds-box slds-p-left_xxx-small slds-theme_default card {styleClass}">`  but its not working.What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such conditional CSS is not supported by LWC, you need to include all the CSS in a class property:

```html
<div class={styleClass}>
```

```js
get styleClass(){
    return `slds-box slds-p-left_xxx-small slds-theme_default card ${this.show ? 'class0': 'class1'}`;
}
```